# Mass transfer apps to adopted storage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, app2sd, adoptable-storage

So now we have excellent adopted storage that lets us use the 
SDcard like it should have always worked. So far so good.

However upgrading from Lollipop via titanium backup hits a snag - TB will always stick the restored apps to internal storage even if adoptive storage is the default after data migrate. Sure you can move them one by one but with 100 apps that's a LOT of fiddling. Is there any way to automate this? A console command to rerun the data migrate?

Link2SD does not work with AS as far as I know. App MGR III claims to have 1-click move but at least on the free version it just plops you into the app info page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some semi-random googling I found the app that will do the job. Apps2SD. It's free, requires root but does batch move apps to adopted storage. It's a bit slow too but beats having to do the "transfer to external" sequence for each app hands down.

For the interested, googling for app for adoptive storage doesn't give you anything useful but googling for link2sd marshmallow links to a XDA thread that mentions Apps2SD as a workaround for Marshmallow. It can create mounting scripts unlike Link2SD but Link2SD will then happily use the 2nd partition if you like it better.

Comment: I have to second Apps2SD PRO as a solution. Force-moving many apps to adoptable was a breeze. Definitively worth the price.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Backup Pro has a batch option to move selected apps to/from adopted storage.

It's worth paying for for this and the usual batch backup/restore functionality.